# Helper Operator Issue in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

I am getting a weird error when trying to return my os in my helper operator. This is the code:

```
std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Item& i) {
    i.display(os);
    return os;
}
```

The compiler I am using is telling me it is inaccessible but I don't know why or how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

`std::ostream` is not copyable, you should return by reference

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Item& i)
//          ^
```

Comment: More to the point, you don't want to return a new ostream, but the one that was passed in.

Comment: so I basically don't return os by itself?

Comment: @user3075178 that's right. and compiler won't allow you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You defined your operator<<() to return ostream - a value - but you took os as a reference, so the return is implicitly invoking a copy constructor for ostream to generate a value to return. There is no copy constructor for ostream, hence the error. Just change the return type of your operator<<() definition to ostream& - then you have reference in, reference out, no need to construct a value, no error.

Comment: Thanks sarah. I have tried tro do that nut the compiler is telling me type name not allowed

Comment: can you paste your revised code and the error message here?

Comment: problem may be with Item...display() needs to be public and const: struct Item { void display( std::ostream & ) const {} };